# Overpass API: Find stairs at the end of a dead end

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Is it possible to search for dead end roads (dead end for vehicles, not for pedestrian) first and then reduce the result by the roads that contain stairs at the dead end?

[image]

```
[out:json];
area[name="London"]->.a;
(
  way(area.a)["highway"~"^(residential|living_street)$"]; /* ["end"="yes"] or ["dead_end"="yes"] doesn't work; */
  way(area.a)["highway"="steps"];
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overpass API release 0.7.61 has a few new features to identify dead end nodes, see [this wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Recurse_(way_cnt,_way_link)) for details.

```
[out:json];
area[name="London"]->.a;
way(area.a)["highway"~"^(residential|living_street)$"];
node(way_link:1);
way(bn)["highway"="steps"];
out geom;
```

Try this query in [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1yzk)